# How to display my database file one subject per one subject

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display my database one subject per one subject.

I want to have `text_one`, `img_one`, *Separation*, `text_two` and `img_two`.

But now, it displays `text_one`, `img_one` *Separation*, `text_one`, `img_one`,  `text_two` and `img_two`.

How can I display my database subject by subject without having any duplicate?

Here's my code:

```
$product = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `fr` WHERE active = '1' AND product = '1' ");

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product)){
if ($rows['text'] != NULL)
        {
            $text .= '<p class="lead">' . $rows['text'] .'</p>';
        }

        if ($rows['img'] != NULL)
        {
            $img .= '<img class="img-responsive"  src="img/description/' . $rows['img'] . '" alt="">';
        }

$products .= '<div class="content-section">
                    <div class="container"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="lead">' . $text.'</p>
                            <div class="col-sm-12" align="center"> '.$img.' </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>';
    }
echo $products;
```

Comment: Strange code... For one thing: you forgot the enclosing curly brackets around the sections that is meant to be the loop block: `while (...) {...}`. That means the `while` loop gets only applied to the single following command, which is `if ($rows['first_text'] != NULL) {...}` here

Comment: And where does $text come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change `$first_text .=` to `$first_text =` and same for `$img` as `$first.=` will concatenate the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's work now. I just do like you say and set each variable to NULL at the top of the while.